# Визуализация свободного падения

Tags: delphi

На форме есть тело, по нажатии кнопки оно падает.Есть алгоритм по которому оно падает на поверхность за определенное время(зависит от высоты). Как можно сделать движение тела на форме равноускоренным а не с постоянной скоростью как сейчас?

```
procedure TMainForm.StartClick(Sender: TObject);
const
g = 9.81;
var
t,h:Double;
begin
h:=sSpinEdit1.Value;
if (h<>0) then
begin
t:=Sqrt((2*h)/g)*1000;//вычисление времени
timePX:= (h*8)/(t/10);//количество пикселей в 10мс
end;
if (MainForm.shp1.top>=MainForm.img1.Height-42)//проверка лежит ли на земле
then
else
tmr1.Enabled:=True;
MainForm.sSpinEdit1.Enabled:=False;
end;

procedure TMainForm.tmr1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
fc:=fc+Frac(timePX);//складывание остатков от timePX
MainForm.shp1.top := MainForm.shp1.top+Trunc(timePX);//Прибавление целой части timePX
if(fc>=1)//Прибавление остатка от timePX
then
begin
  MainForm.shp1.top := MainForm.shp1.top+Trunc(fc);
  fc:=fc-1;
end;
if (MainForm.shp1.top>=MainForm.img1.Height-42)
then tmr1.Enabled:=False;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё довольно просто, вам нужно посчитать ускорение предмета, его можно расчитать по простой формуле ускорение=расстояние/(время*время), исходя из этого формула движения будет

```
accel:=len/(time*time); //считать до начала движения
speed:=speed+accel;     // считать каждую еденицу времени
pos:=pos+speed;         //считать каждую еденицу времени
```

Итого выйдет что тело двигаясь равноускорено пройдет len расстояния за time времени.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас у вас скорее всего

> `Top:=Top+1`

А сделать можно так:

```
k:=k+0.1;
Top:=Top+k;
```

То есть с каждой итерацией коэффициент будет линейно расти.

Comment: Там все несколько сложнее. Сначала вычисляется время за которое оно должно упасть , на основе этого времени и высоты вычисляется сколько пикселей оно должно проходить каждые 10мс. Как сделать так чтобы оно ускорялось но время падение оставалось одно и тоже?

Comment: Или показывайте свой код или вызывайте телепатов.

хотя ускорение все равно будет с помощью изменяющегося коэффициента

Comment: добавил код